# How to check if a language is regular

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I'm currently studying a formal languages & automate module on my course and I have been asked to answer the following question:

> Which of the languages below are regular? If the language is regular, justify your answer by giving the corresponding regular grammar, or by referring to lemmas
>
> $$\{a^n b^m \mid n, m \ge 1\}$$

I've worked with grammars and derivations of productions of grammars but I'm unsure how to prove if a language is regular or not. 
After researching online I believe I need to use pumping lemma but I'm unsure how to actually use the lemma to solve a question like this and would appreciate if somebody could do a step by step on how to solve a question like the one above or point me in the direction of some useful material.

I believe the above language is context-free not regular.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Because $n$ and $m$ are completely independent of each other here, you should suspect that the language **is** regular. And in fact it is. Now that you know that, can you find a regular grammar that generates it?

Comment: The pumping lemma is used to prove that languages aren't regular. In this case, the language really is regular, so no pumping lemma necessary (in fact, you probably can't solve the problem with it).

Comment: Ah right, I forgot about those rules. Yeh ok I think i've got a corresponding grammar for that language. 

Seeing as i've written the question wrong, is it possible you could show me a pumping lemma proof of any language to disprove that a language is regular?

Comment: You might want to look at [Computer Science.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) for information on proofs with the pumping lemma; in particular, see [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) question.

Comment: Ok great Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use lemmas, note that 
$$ L:= \{a^nb^m : n,m \ge 1\} = \{a^n : n \ge 1\} \circ \{b^m : m \ge 1\} $$
that both languages on the right are regular, and regular languages are closed under concatenation.

To give a grammar, show that 
$$ S \to aA, A \to aA | B,  B \to bB | b $$
with starting symbol $S$ generates $L$.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Because I've asked a question and given a language which is regular. 
If I have the example 
{ba^n bc^n | n ≥ 1}
Which I don't think is regular because of repetition of n, how would I prove that this isn't a regular language using lemmas?

Comment: Right. This language is not regular. What lemmas about and examples of (non-)regular languages do you know?

Comment: I know that a regular language allows repetition for one segment of a string and I know that context-free allows for repetition for two segments of a string (which I believe is the case in the example I just gave). 

I'm under the impression I need to use pumping lemma to prove? Although i'm unsure. 

Thanks

Comment: Right. The pumping lemma will be of use here. You should formulate the question as a new one, containing also the statement of the pumping lemma for regular languages you know.

Comment: Are you able to give me an example of solving with the pumping lemma (Doesn't have to be the example i gave). I've tried looking online tutorials on proofs with pumping lemma but I can't get me head around it as of yet.

Comment: A comment containig such an example would be quite long, so you should formulate your thoughts as a new question ... this will also attract others to give examples ...